# Matlab: is it possible to find the radius of each cluster when using the kmeans function?

Tags: matlab, k-means

From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) there are no options to find out the radius of each cluster. The closest to what I want was the command:

```
[IDX,C,sumd] = kmeans(X,k)
```

which returns `sumd` for each cluster the sum of distances between the points of the cluster to the centroid of the cluster.

Is it possible to find the radius of each cluster specifically?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by radius, but I see you can get this as output: `[IDX,C,sumd,D]`. I would say that the maximum distance to the center of each cluster would be (a lower bound for) the corresponding radius.

Comment: thank you this must be the answer.

Comment: I would recommend you to close the question in that case.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: instead, you could put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you define (a lower bound for) the radius as the maximum distance that any point has to the center of the cluster that it is in.

When looking at the documentation, a fourth output argument is available, hence the function call can be:

```
[IDX,C,sumd, D] = kmeans(X,k);
```

Now you can see what the maximum distance is within each cluster and you have a minimum of what each radius will be.